# requirements for merging two Pandas DataFrame

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, merge, etl

I do not know why I cannot merge two Dataframes based on their Alpha-3 code and iso_code as follow although the '"' were removed before merging:

```
import pandas as pd

vac = pd.read_csv('https://raw.githubusercontent.com/owid/covid-19-data/master/public/data/vaccinations/vaccinations.csv')
world = pd.read_csv('https://gist.githubusercontent.com/tadast/8827699/raw/f5cac3d42d16b78348610fc4ec301e9234f82821/countries_codes_and_coordinates.csv').
```

The outcome when I merged was just column names.

Could anyone explain, please?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Taking a look inside the data, you will notice that `world` df will contain quotes inside the Alpha-3 code:

```
          Country Alpha-2 code Alpha-3 code Numeric code Latitude (average)  \
0     Afghanistan         "AF"        "AFG"          "4"               "33"   
1         Albania         "AL"        "ALB"          "8"               "41"   
2         Algeria         "DZ"        "DZA"         "12"               "28"   
3  American Samoa         "AS"        "ASM"         "16"         "-14.3333"   
4         Andorra         "AD"        "AND"         "20"             "42.5"   

  Longitude (average)  
0                "65"  
1                "20"  
2                 "3"  
3              "-170"  
4               "1.6"
```

So you will want to get rid of that with:

```py
# note the space is intentional, to get rid of blank spaces
world['Alpha-3 code'] = world['Alpha-3 code'].str.strip(' "')
```

Comment: Thank you so much. I did use replace('"', '') before posting the question, rather than strip(' "').